# Using the Python shell in Vi mode on Windows

Tags: python, windows, vi, readline

I know that you can use the Python shell in Vi mode on Unix-like operating systems. For example, I have this line in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

This lets me use Vi-style editing inside the Python shell.

But can this be made to work when using Python on a Windows XP box? I'm using the pre-built Python for Windows downloaded directly from python.org.

I'm guessing that the Windows version does not use the GNU Readline library, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong. :)

Comment: Can't say for sure, but it might work if you download cygwin, and use python in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [PyReadline](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline)

Setup your `pyreadlineconfig.ini` and `PYTHONSTARTUPFILE` files as per the PyReadline instructions.

Then add the following to your `pyreadlineconfig.ini` file:

```
set_mode("vi")
history_filename("~/.pythonhistory")
history_length(200)
```

The history settings must be after the mode setting.

Commands such as `ESC` `K` to jump to the previous command now work.

Comment: I just installed Python 2.7 on Windows 7, then followed your instructions. Although vi mode seems to be working, scrolling through history with ESC K doesn't work. After I exit the Python interpreter I see that it is creating a .pythonhistory file, but it is blank. Any ideas?

Comment: @BrianNeal Looks like a bug in the code.
I've written a patch for you. https://github.com/willbr/pyreadline 
Download then `python setup.py install` should fix it.
Also I've sent the pyreadline author a pull request & logged a bug on github.

Comment: Excellent work! I regret not being able to upvote this more than once!

Answer (score 2):

[cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) can give you many Unix-y advantages on your "Windows XP box" (using its own Python build, among other things -- avoiding some of the Windows-only limitations of the "standard Windows builds") -- try it out!

Comment: I'm aware of cygwin and use it all the time, but for this application I must use Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it looks like you can use the [PyReadline](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/PyReadline/Intro) library in conjunction with [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) to get most of the Vi functionality I miss on Linux. I still haven't figured out how I can hit `ESC` and then `k` to scroll through the previous command history.