# How to enable vim style command line editing in python interpreter in anaconda windows install in cygwin environment

Tags: python-3.x, windows, anaconda, cygwin

Installed anaconda 3.x windows edition on a windows 7 desktop. I would like to be able to do vim style command line editing on the python interpreter started from a Cygwin shell.

I know Cygwin also comes with python and since I need to use the latest version of python I have a need to use the anaconda distribution of windows.

With anaconda windows image installed at
    /usr/local/anaconda3
went through info at
    [Using the Python shell in Vi mode on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837693/using-the-python-shell-in-vi-mode-on-windows)
and did these steps

```
export CONDA_BASE_DIR=/usr/local/anaconda3
export SHELLOPTS
set -o igncr
export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=root
export CONDA_PREFIX=${CONDA_BASE_DIR}

cp /usr/local/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/pyreadline/configuration/startup.py
/cygdrive/c/Users/my_windows_login
cp /usr/local/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/pyreadline/configuration/pyreadlinecon
fig.ini
/cygdrive/c/Users/my_windows_login
export PYTHONSTARTUPPATH=c:\\Users\\my_windows_login\\startup.py
```

Edit
    /cygdrive/c/Users/my_windows_login/pyreadlineconfig.ini
to uncomment

```
set_mode("vi")
history_filename("~/.pythonhistory")
history_length(200)
```

Starting up python interpreter as

```
$ conda activate base
(base) $ python -i $PYTHONSTARTUP
```

but vi editing mode is not enabled in command line of the interpreter as observed by hitting Esc-k.

Without -i flag, python windows binary will not startup in interactive mode in Cygwin environment.
Since the interpreter when started with -i flag, does not read what is in $PYTHONSTARTUP, $PYTHONSTARTUP is explicitly specified in command line so that the startup.py script can be executed at startup time.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded

```
winpty-0.4.3-cygwin-2.8.0-x64.tar.gz
```

from

```
https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/releases
```

and extracted it to /usr/local of cygwin installation.

readline config needs to be in $HOME of cygwin as opposed to c:\users\<my_windows_login>

```
$ cp /usr/local/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/pyreadline/configuration/startup.py $HOME
$ cp /usr/local/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/pyreadline/configuration/pyreadlineconfig.ini $HOME
```

With above setup, when I run anaconda python as

```
$ PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/Library/bin:$PATH winpty /usr/local/anaconda3/python
```

vi style command line editing works fine.